# sqlite3_prepare_v2 failing

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Could anyone explain to me why this if statement is not triggering? The database opens just fine, it's just that I can't retrieve any values from the database. Also, the table name is correct as well.

```
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK) {


        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

            char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            char *addressChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
            NSString *address = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:addressChars];

            PersonInfo *info = [[PersonInfo alloc] initWithUniqueID:uniqueId name:name address:address];

            [returnArray addObject:info];


        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Break the if statement open and catch the return code - that should give you some idea of why the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` call is failing

Also, we'd need to know what the query was to try and debug it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM CON_PARTENT; .. Just selecting everything from the table

Comment: I get nothing in the return statement.

Comment: Check for error codes, and call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) in that case.