# How to call sqlite3_errmsg to know why sqlite3_prepare_v2 is failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

C based function `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is returning 1. I simply want to know the error message in readable form and to correct my code. I was learning this as a tutorial from raywinderlich blogs. I have come across `sqlite3_errmsg` and I have no idea how to use `sqlite3_errmsg` function.

Although same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286259/sqlite3-prepare-v2-failing), unfortunately still is unanswered.

I wanna know the error and correction will highly be appreciated. thanks.

```
- (NSArray *)failedBankInfos {
    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT id, name, city, state FROM failed_banks ORDER BY close_date DESC";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int tmp  = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
    NSLog(@"%i",tmp); // printing 1
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            char *cityChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            char *stateChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
            NSString *city = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cityChars];
            NSString *state = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:stateChars];
            NSLog(@"name is  : %@",name);
             NSLog(@"city is : %@",city);
            FailedBankInfo *info = [[FailedBankInfo alloc]
                                    initWithUniqueId:uniqueId name:name city:city state:state];
            [retval addObject:info];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        // if part is failing and control is arriving in else.
    }
    return retval;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3_errmsg()` like:

```
NSLog(@"Database Error Message : %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
```

Also you can use `sqlite3_errstr()`.

> The sqlite3_errmsg() and sqlite3_errmsg16() return English-language
>   text that describes the error, as either UTF-8 or UTF-16 respectively.
>   Memory to hold the error message string is managed internally. The
>   application does not need to worry about freeing the result. However,
>   the error string might be overwritten or deallocated by subsequent
>   calls to other SQLite interface functions.
>
> The sqlite3_errstr() interface returns the English-language text that
>   describes the result code, as UTF-8. Memory to hold the error message
>   string is managed internally and must not be freed by the application.

Reference [SQLite Error Messages](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)

Comment: Be carful that sqlite3_errstr() is not available before SQLite v 3.7.15, so not available with iOS7.x.