# Make arrays from json and save arrays in columns of SQLite in objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am retrieving data from my `json file` and it contains the `timings` for `sunrise`, `sunset` and `midnight`. I want to make `array for sunrise` , `array for sunset` and `array for midnight`. and save my arrays in `sunriseColumn` , `sunsetColumn` and `midnightColumn` in SQLite.

But I am little bit confused how can I do that in a proper way.

What I have in my `ViewDidLoad()`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self saveinDatabase];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/macbook/Desktop/Test/Test/myFile.json"];
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Json data is here %@", fileContent);
```

saving data in dictionary

```
NSArray *data = [[theFeedString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"data"];
for (NSDictionray *dict in data) {
NSString *timings = [[dict objectForKey:@"timings"] intValue];
NSArray *sunriseArray = [objectForKey:@"sunrise"]
NSArray *sunsetArray = [objectForKey:@"sunset"]
NSArray *midnight = [objectForKey:@"midnight"]
}
```

in my console I get all the data from my json and my json look like this

```
{
"data": [
{
"timings": {
"Sunrise": "07:14 (PKT)",
"Sunset": "18:15 (PKT)",
"Midnight": "00:45 (PKT)"
}
},
{
"timings": {
"Sunrise": "07:13 (PKT)",
"Sunset": "06:40 (PKT)",
"Midnight": "00:45 (PKT)"
}
}
]
}
```

a method for storing data in `SQLite`

```
-(void) saveinDatabase {

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

_dbPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.db"]];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath] == NO) {

    const char *dbPathagain = [_dbPath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {
        char *errorMessage;
        const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jsontable(ID integer primary key, sunrise text, sunset text, midnight text)";

        NSLog(@"created table success");

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *dbPathagain = [ _dbPath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            NSString *insertSQLData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO jsontable(sunrise, sunset, midnight) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", sunriseArray, sunsetArray, midnightArray];
            const char *insert_statement = [insertSQLData UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                NSLog(@"data added successfully");
                NSLog(@"here is sunrise times %@", sunriseArray);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"could not add timings");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(_DB);
        }

        if (sqlite3_exec(_DB, sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"failed to create table");
        }
        sqlite3_close(_DB);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to open db or cretate table");
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: This code will save all 3 array in single row. Do you really want to achieve this?

Comment: can I run loops so that item by item will be added from three arrays to a row by row

Comment: If you want to store single data in single row then there is no need to create separate array. Just loop through to your array named "data" and fetch each dictionary and store it in database

Comment: would you help me in this to give an answer

Comment: can you tell me why you should want 3 different array? and where you facing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in you code:

Pass your "data" array to method.

```
 NSDictionary *dict = @{
                               @"data": @[
                                       @{
                                           @"timings": @{
                                                   @"Sunrise": @"07:14 (PKT)",
                                                   @"Sunset": @"18:15 (PKT)",
                                                   @"Midnight": @"00:45 (PKT)"
                                                   }
                                           },
                                       @{
                                           @"timings": @{
                                                   @"Sunrise": @"07:13 (PKT)",
                                                   @"Sunset": @"06:40 (PKT)",
                                                   @"Midnight": @"00:45 (PKT)"
                                                   }
                                           }
                                       ]
                               };
     NSArray *arrData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"data"]];
    [self saveinDatabase:arrData];
```

Replace method with following code:

```
-(void) saveinDatabase:(NSArray*) arrData {

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    _dbPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.db"]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath] == NO) {

        const char *dbPathagain = [_dbPath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            char *errorMessage;
            const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jsontable(ID integer primary key, sunrise text, sunset text, midnight text)";

            NSLog(@"created table success");

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            const char *dbPathagain = [ _dbPath UTF8String];

            if(sqlite3_open(dbPathagain, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK ) {


                for (int i=0; i<arrData.count; i++) {

                    NSDictionary *dictTiming = [[arrData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"timings"];
                    NSString *insertSQLData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO jsontable(sunrise, sunset, midnight) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", [dictTiming objectForKey:@"Sunrise"], [dictTiming objectForKey:@"Sunset"], [dictTiming objectForKey:@"Midnight"]];
                    const char *insert_statement = [insertSQLData UTF8String];
                    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

                    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                        NSLog(@"data added successfully");
                        NSLog(@"here is sunrise times %@", sunriseArray);
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"could not add timings");
                    }

                }


                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_DB);
            }

            if (sqlite3_exec(_DB, sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(_DB);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"failed to open db or cretate table");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but there is Ann error "failed to open db or cretate table

Comment: What is the exact error is appearing? "failed to open db or cretate table" is the error message that you have logged. Can you share error message provided by system

Comment: `2018-03-26 12:55:25.690625+0500 Test[1260:91590] failed to open db or cretate table
2018-03-26 12:55:25.700825+0500 Test[1260:91590] Json data is here {
  "data": [
    {
      "timings": {`

Comment: `// Open the test.db file
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db); // <-- creates DB if not found ??

if( rc ){
    // failed
    NSLog(stderr, @"ERROR: Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
} ` Use this code to see error provided by system

Comment: this method gives me error would you please update this in answer plz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546711/how-to-call-sqlite3-errmsg-to-know-why-sqlite3-prepare-v2-is-failing check this link to print error

Comment: `2018-03-26 14:42:51.969450+0500 Test[1606:159853] failed to open db or cretate table
2018-03-26 14:42:51.969624+0500 Test[1606:159853] Database Error Message : unable to open database file`

Comment: I think I have multiple data so it gives error as we are inserting multiple data? what you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167551/discussion-between-priya-and-ios-developer).